# running the same task on multiple agents in my Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a block like:

```groovy
stage('Clone on win10x64-b-ut') {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'win10x64-b-ut'
        }
    }
    steps {
        gitClone()
    }
}    

stage('Clone on win81x64-b-ut') {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'win81x64-b-ut'
        }
    }
    steps {
        gitClone()
    }
}
```

I want to run the same task in somewhat like a loop by just changing the labels. I want to eliminate redundancy as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421660/9498358

If you don't want to run stages in parallel (like in the linked answer), you can add a for loop inside the script block, so it will look something like this:

```groovy
def generateStage(nodeLabel) {
    return {
        stage("Clone on ${nodeLabel}") {
            agent {
                node {
                    label nodeLabel
                }
            }
            steps {
                gitClone()
            }
        } 
    }
}

// ...

stage('Clone') {
    steps {
        script {
            def allNodes = ['win10x64-b-ut', 'win81x64-b-ut']

            for (def i = 0; i < allNodes.size(); i++) {
                generateStage(allNodes[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the answer gives exception for def i and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421660/9498358 has good result.

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer is not working. Expecially the def part.

This is working:

```
def generateStage(nodeLabel) {
    stage("Runs on ${nodeLabel}") {
        node(nodeLabel) {
            sh 'hostname'
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label '!docker'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Run') {
            steps {
                script {
                    nodes = nodesByLabel(label: 'docker')

                    for (node in nodes) {
                        generateStage(node)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we add more than one labels using nodesByLabel? My intention is to create and execute same stage added into 'generateStage' function.

Comment: This indeed work but I have strange issue; the array I get start with a comma [, VM1, VM2] which cause generateStage to run on a random agent that don't have the label, any ideas ?