# Jenkins declarative pipeline 1.3 run parallel for all jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have setup a pipeline project similar to https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel-stages-example
and it works fine.

But I have created the same project for different jobs, so rather than creating new jobs can I run for loop for all jobs e.g. `jobs = [job1, job2, job3]` and run above pipeline code for different jobs.

Something similar to https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script-example

Can I use a for loop or similar logic to run a declarative pipeline?

I found similar question but not sure how to modify fo this [Is it possible to create parallel Jenkins Declarative Pipeline stages in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894308/is-it-possible-to-create-parallel-jenkins-declarative-pipeline-stages-in-a-loop)

Comment: I am trying to add into declarative syntax so I can add this to Shared Library

Comment: `Is it possible to create parallel Jenkins Declarative Pipeline stages in a loop?` Max's answer does it exactly how  you want it ...Just copy the same thing and replace ["JobA", "JobB", "JobC"] to [job1, job2, job3] ...it will work

Comment: You can check https://github.com/jenkins-infra/pipeline-library/blob/master/vars/buildPlugin.groovy and get the idea of how it's done in Jenkins itself by using a Map, I tried it my self and I came up with a weird error popping up, you might succeed though. Let me know :).

Comment: @rohitthomas If I tried as Max's answer won't it be `Scripted Pipeline` syntax? If I'm using `def` method, and I will have to add all declarative methods in `def` method such as `agent`, `environment` etc. I thought you can't use `def` method with 1.3 syntax

Comment: this is the format I am looking at https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/#about-the-author, not finding any example how to incorporate for loop with this, any pointers are appreciated

Comment: Where exactly are you facing the issue ... I tried it based on the format you wanted with Max's answer it is working fine and Declarative is built on top of Scripted pipeline so def will work :)

Comment: hmm I thought if I have to move code to Shared library i.e. under `def call { pipeline {}}` I can't have other `def` method,