# Jenkinsfile: How to provide a function to `parallel` block, instead of a predefined map?

Tags: jenkins

[This really helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421660/7023816), got me 95% of the way there. Using this solution, I'm able to start `n` build stages in parallel. However, the map of parallel stages is essentially hardcoded. I want to be able to create it dynamically. The first step in this process is changing `parallelStagesMap` from a map, to a function that returns a map.

Unfortunatey, this small change causes my build to fail without any apparent error logs related to syntax.

How can I accomplish this? Am I using malformed Groovy syntax? I'd be grateful for any help.

```
def jobs = ["JobA", "JobB", "JobC"]

def parallelStagesMap() {                 // This is now a function that returns a map.
    return jobs.collectEntries {
        ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
    }
}
def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: ${job}") {
            echo "This is ${job}."
            sh script: "sleep 15"
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap()      // I call the function here.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working solution! It's not perfect, because I would like to extract the `jobs.collectEntries` part to my own function, but now I can define the contents of my parallel stages inline, instead of at the top of the file!

I tried writing a function matching the same signature as `Map.collectEntries`: (`{ Closure -> Map }`), but the Jenkins build fails without any logs once it hits my function. If someone's able to work that out, I'd be grateful.

```
def jobs = ["JobA", "JobB", "JobC"]

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel jobs.collectEntries { j ->
                        ["${j}" : { job -> return {
                            stage("stage: ${job}") {
                                echo "This is ${job}."
                                sh script: "sleep 15"
                            }
                        }}(j)]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```