# Running one particular job in parallel on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have multiple jobs set on Jenkins. There are only one executor on masters, there are many other slaves. I want to create a job which would run on a separate job queue or a separate executor concurrently. How can I achieve this in simplest way? Can it be achieved without modifying slaves?

The next thing is how can I achieve running on any new build for this job in parallel. Rest of the jobs set should not be disturbed and interfered.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you need to configure a particular job to run on a slave node...
In order to achieve that you can 1st add a node to the Jenkins master. There you have a place to add a label to that slave node. The in the pipeline script of your job you can edit it as follows.

```
pipeline {
        agent {
            node {
                label '<YOUR SLAVE NODE LABEL>'
            }
        }
}
```

In the latter part of the question, you have asked to run parallel jobs. Please refer to the [parallel job documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/) If you need to add sequential stages refer to the [sequential stage documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/#running-multiple-stages-in-a-parallel-branch) If you want to create a dynamic parallel job this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894308/is-it-possible-to-create-parallel-jenkins-declarative-pipeline-stages-in-a-loop) would help you.

Comment: what if I remove node?

Comment: Yes, it will work after you remove the node. `agent { label "<YOUR SLAVE NODE LABEL>" }`. But you need to provide the label which your Jenkins slave use. Then only your slave will get triggered to do the job.