# Jenkins Parallel Build reads in an empty map, but it held data in a previous stage

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Total noobie trying to make a parallel build more dynamic.

Using this declarative script https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421660/14335065
instead of reading in a prepopulated map `def jobs = ["JobA", "JobB", "JobC"]`, which works perfectly.

I am trying to read in from a global map variable `JOBS = []` which I populate in a stage using `JOBS.add("JobAAA")` syntax.

Printing out `JOBS` in a pipeline stage shows there are contents within,

```
JOBS map is [JobAAA, JobBBB, JobCCC]
```

but when I use it to generate a parallel build it seems to become empty and I am getting error message

`No branches to run`

I know I must be mixing my understands up somewhere, but can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Here is the code I am fighting with

```
def jobs = ["JobA", "JobB", "JobC"]
JOBS_MAP = []

def parallelStagesMap = jobs.collectEntries() {
   ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def parallelStagesMapJOBS = JOBS_MAP.collectEntries(){
   ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(job) {
   return {
       stage("Build: ${job}") {
           echo "This is ${job}."
       }
   }
}

pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
       stage('populate JOBS map') {
           steps {
               script {
                   JOBS_MAP.add("JobAAA")
                   JOBS_MAP.add("JobBBB")
                   JOBS_MAP.add("JobCCC")
               }
           }
       }
       stage('print out JOBS map'){
           steps {
               echo "JOBS_MAP map is ${JOBS_MAP}"
           }
       }
       stage('parallel job stage') {
           steps {
               script {
                   parallel parallelStagesMap
               }
           }
       }
       stage('parallel JOBS stage') {
           steps {
               script {
                   parallel parallelStagesMapJOBS
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Before your pipeline is run, you create an empty `JOBS_MAP` and then iterate it to create `parallelStagesMapJOBS` (which comes out empty). The fact that you populate `JOBS_MAP` later is  not affecting `parallelStagesMapJOBS` which is still empty.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MaratC on reading the code top-down that makes sense. 
But I was lead to be believed that declaring a variable at the vary top without `def` would make it `global` and therefore can be accessed anywhere at anytime throughout the pipeline script. 
And if this is correct I am populating the 'global' variable before I am calling the `parallelStagesMapJOBS` method.
Failing this I must have my understanding of the script flow completely wrong?

Comment: Both `JOBS_MAP` and `parallelStagesMapJOBS` are global and they both are defined as empty before your pipeline runs. You may want to move your definition of `parallelStagesMapJOBS` into the pipeline at any stage AFTER you populate `JOBS_MAP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def jobs = ["JobA", "JobB", "JobC"]
JOBS_MAP = []

def generateStage(job) {
   return {
       stage("Build: ${job}") {
           echo "This is ${job}."
       }
   }
}

pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
       stage('populate JOBS map') {
           steps {
               script {
                   JOBS_MAP.add("JobAAA")
                   JOBS_MAP.add("JobBBB")
                   JOBS_MAP.add("JobCCC")
               }
           }
       }
       stage('print out JOBS map'){
           steps {
               echo "JOBS_MAP map is ${JOBS_MAP}"
           }
       }
       stage('parallel job stage') {
           steps {
               script {
                   def parallelStagesMap = jobs.collectEntries() {
                       ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
                   }
                   parallel parallelStagesMap
               }
           }
       }
       stage('parallel JOBS stage') {
           steps {
               script {
                   def parallelStagesMapJOBS = JOBS_MAP.collectEntries(){
                      ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
                   }

                   parallel parallelStagesMapJOBS
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```