# Jenkins pipelines with parallel and different containers

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

So I am already running Jenkins pipelines with parallel base on the example from: [Is it possible to create parallel Jenkins Declarative Pipeline stages in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894308/is-it-possible-to-create-parallel-jenkins-declarative-pipeline-stages-in-a-loop)

I want to run each job in different isolated container, the agent name should be the same to all of them. Tried a few options all of them ended up withe errors, I think I  need to use both declarative and scripted but not sure how.
Things I tired:

```
def generateTerraformStage(env) {
    return {
        agent { label 'local_terraform' }
        stage("stage: Terraform ${TERRAFORM_ACTION} ${env}") {
                echo "${env}"
                sleep 30
        }
    }
}
```

```
stage('parallel stages') {
    agent { label 'local_terraform' }
    steps {
        script {
            parallel parallelStagesMapEnvironment
        }
    }
}
```

One of the errors I got during testing:

```
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps" and "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@560f3533"
```

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps"
and "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@560f3533"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic parallel stages could be created only by using Scripted Pipelines. The API built-it Declarative Pipeline is not available (like `agent`, `options`, `when` etc.).

I don't see any information that you really need dynamic stages (e.g. based on the value returned by a 3rd-party service), so I prepared two solutions:

- dynamic parallel stages - stages are generated based on something
- static parallel stages - you know all stages (the `when` block could be used to disable these which are not needed - e.g. passed in parameters)

```
pipeline {
  // ...
  stages {
    stage('dynamic parallel stages') {
      steps {
        script {
           // params.ENVS == ['envA', 'envB', 'envC']
           def values = params.ENVS.split(',')
           def stages = [:]
           for (def value in values) {
             stages[value] = generateTerraformStage(value)
           }
           parallel stages
        }
      }
    }
    stage('static parallel stages') {
      parallel {
        stage('envA') {
          agent { label 'local_terraform' }
          when {
            expression { return params.ENVS.split(',').contains('envA') }
          }
          steps {
            terraformStageLogic 'envA'
          }
        }
        stage('envB') {
          agent { label 'local_terraform' }
          when {
            expression { return params.ENVS.split(',').contains('envB') }
          }
          steps {
            terraformStageLogic 'envB'
          }
        }
        stage('envC') {
          agent { label 'local_terraform' }
          when {
            expression { return params.ENVS.split(',').contains('envC') }
          }
          steps {
            terraformStageLogic 'envC'
          }
        }
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
}

Closure<Void> generateTerraformStage(env) {
  return {
    node('local_terraform') {
      stage("stage: Terraform ${TERRAFORM_ACTION} ${env}") {
        echo "${env}"
        sleep 30
      }
    }
  }
}

void terraformStageLogic(env) {
  echo "${env}"
  sleep 30
}
```

When you don't use the workspace in the stage responsible for generating or executing other stages (`dynamic parallel stages` and `static parallel stages`) then you don't need to allocate any node to it (waste of resources).