# Jenkins kubernetes plugin using 2 podTemplates according to job use case

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-kubernetes

I have 2 podTemplates inside my kubernetes cloud plugin but I fail to understand how to tag my pipeline jobs to use the second podTemplate.
It just keeps using the first one I configured as a default.

My use case is this - I want to tag several jobs to run on a different k8s node group.
Already tried using a label as their [docs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#using-a-label) say but it just doesn't work.

I have 2 pod templates, both configured with container names which are different.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70853967/13110835) it can give you a useful direction.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there's a way to reference to podTemplate without configuring it as part of the pipeline (its already configured in the plugin as part of its installation)

Comment: In that case just use the label (in the agent directive) that you assigned to the pre-configured pod template, the pipeline will then automatically use it.