# convert jenkinsfile agent label switch to multiple embeded podSpec

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Team,
I have this function to pick podtemplate based on login and it works but I need to convert it to not use template but use pod spec for dynamic agent scheduling. any hint how can I achieve it? with one agent am able to do it but need to do for three so am stuck.

```
def buildAgent() {
    agent = 'artifacts'
    if (params.Cuda) {
        agent =  'artifacts-gpu'
    }
    if (params.'Image Targets'.contains('drive')) {
        agent = 'artifacts-drive'
    }
    return agent
}
```

i have three specs for each agent above. how can i replace them?

`artifacts` podSpec

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
spec:
  containers:
  - name: argocd
    image: image.com/third_party/argocd-jenkins-agent:2.2
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
        name: "workspace-volume"
        readOnly: false
    hostNetwork: false
```

`artifacts-gpu` podSpec

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
spec:
  .
  .
```

`artifacts-drive` podSpec

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
spec:
  .
  .
```

single agent pipeline works like below but am not sure how to do for multiple agents.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      cloud 'ipp-stuff'
      yaml '''
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
spec:
'''
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Check out [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70853967/13110835) It is similar to what you want to achieve.