# jenkins declarative pipeline set variables derived from parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using a declarative pipeline in a Jenkinsfile but I would like to derive some variables from a parameter.
For example given:

```
parameters {
   choice(name: 'Platform',choices: ['Debian9', 'CentOS7'], description: 'Target OS platform', )
}
```

I would like to add a block like:

```
script {
  switch(param.Platform) {
     case "Centos7":
         def DockerFile = 'src/main/docker/Jenkins-Centos.Dockerfile'
         def PackageType = 'RPM'
         def PackageSuffix = '.rpm'
         break
     case "Debian9":
     default:
         def DockerFile = 'src/main/docker/Jenkins-Debian.Dockerfile'
         def PackageType = 'DEB'
         def PackageSuffix = '.deb'
         break
  }
}
```

Such that I can use variables elsewhere in the pipeline. For example:

```
agent { 
   dockerfile {
       filename "$DockerFile"
   }
}
```

etc..

but script is illegal in the parameter, environment & agent sections.
It can only be used in steps.

I need to use the parameter in the agent block and I want to avoid repeating myself where the variables are used in different steps.

Is there a sane way to achieve this? My preferences in order are:

- a declarative pipeline
- a scripted pipeline (less good)
- via a plugin to the Jenkins UI (least good)

A shared library might be appropriate here regardless of whether it is actually shared.

The intention is to support a multi-configuration project by creating a parameterised build and invoking it for different parameter sets with a red/blue status light for each configuration.
It could be that I have assumed an 'old fashioned' design. In which case an acceptable answer would explain the modern best practice for creating a multi-configuration multi-branch pipeline. Something like: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000088431-Create-a-Matrix-like-flow-with-Pipeline or [Jenkins Pipeline Multiconfiguration Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601999/jenkins-pipeline-multiconfiguration-project)

See also [Multiconfiguration / matrix build pipeline in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56046541/1569204) for less specific discussion of best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Never really used the Jenkins declarative pipeline before but I think the way you refer to params is incorrect?

I think it might be: `${params.Platform}` or `params.Platform` instead of `param`.

So something like the below maybe?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('example') {
            steps {
                script {
                    switch(${params.Platform}) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, never really used it before so not 100%. I was just looking at the syntax used for parameters on the docs: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Comment: The issue is not the syntax for the switch (which is down to me being new to groovy) but where I can put it. I need the parameter for the agent block. Is a script block legal there?

Comment: I see. I didn't realise that was your issue. Is there a need for your parameters to have the numbers in them? For example, something like this may work: `filename "src/main/docker/Jenkins-$Platform.Dockerfile"` if you change the parameter to only allow options of "Debian" and "Centos".

Answer (score 0):

I think that the key for solving your issue is the declaration of your variables. Do not use `def` if you want your variable to be accessible from other stages.

Here is an example of a solution for your issue :

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'Platform',choices: ['Debian9', 'CentOS7'], description: 'Target OS platform', )
    }
    stages{
        stage('Setting stage'){
            agent any
            steps {
                script {
                    switch(params.Platform){
                        case 'CentOS7' :
                            DockerFile = 'src/main/docker/Jenkins-Centos.Dockerfile'
                            PackageType = 'RPM'
                            PackageSuffix = '.rpm'
                            break
                        case 'Debian9' :
                            DockerFile = 'src/main/docker/Jenkins-Debian.Dockerfile'
                            PackageType = 'DEB'
                            PackageSuffix = '.deb'
                            break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Echo stage'){
            agent { 
                dockerfile {
                    filename "$DockerFile"
                }
            }
            steps{
                echo PackageType
                echo PackageSuffix
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is definitely possible on windows:

```
stage('var from groovy') {
    steps {
        script {
             anvar = "foo"
        }

        bat "${anyvar}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an example that I have in production

```
def dest_app_instance = "${params.Destination}"

switch(dest_app_instance) {
  case "CASE1":
    dest_server = "server1"
    break
  case "CASE2":
    dest_server = "server2"
    break 
}
```

Comment: but where in a declarative pipeline can you place that so that the parameter can be used to set the agent?

Comment: @Bruce Adams, I missed the part about it being a declarative pipeline, I'm using scripted pipelines.